# How to get the value of a Property Object in Python?

Tags: python, properties, cgkit

I'm using the ***cgkit.wintab*** module in python to access x,y coordinates of my Wacom tablet. The command `cgkit.wintab.Packet.x` is supposed to give me the value of the x co-ordinate of the touch on the tablet. Instead I get the response `<property object at (hex memory address)>`.

How do I extract the value of the x co-ordinate from this object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`cgkit.wintab.Packet` is a class. You need to look up `x` on an instance of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: That still doesn't give me the value of the x co-ordinate. How do I pull out that particular data from the property object that results?

Comment: If you're getting a property object, you're still doing something that amounts to `cgkit.wintab.Packet.x` instead of getting an instance of `Packet` and looking up `instance.x`. I don't know where `Packet` instances would come from, but you might want to look at the `cgkit.wintab.Context` class.

Comment: ok, that was utter confusion on my part. I created an instance of it and am now getting values - thought they are all O. Any idea how i could rectify this?

Comment: You can't just make an instance and expect it to represent the event you want. It'd be like trying to find the length of a list by creating a new list and getting the length of that. Figure out what part of the API provides `Packet`s representing the events you need and inspect those `Packet`s for the data you want. Again, I suggest looking at `cgkit.wintab.Context`.